# How to disable Sexual Innuendo rating games from my game Ads - AdMob

Tags: admob

I have disabled most sensitive categories including Reference to sex, and Sexual & Reproductive Health, but my game still shows game ads for games rated as "+12 Sexual Innuendo and +12 Nudity." Is there a way to remove these "Sexual Innuendo, Nudity puzzle and love story games" as they do clearly have reference to sexual content games.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you include how you have tried configuring admob to not show these kinds of ads?

Comment: Sorry for the late respone... Basically I went into Apps>select the app>Blocking controls>Ad content rating, select PG.